# Slick Carousel jumping when changing width of active slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, slick.js

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/br24p3Lr/

I'm trying to get the animation correct when changing to a new active slide. I've tried different methods to fix this animation but I'm kinda dead in the water currently.

HTML:

```
    <section class="ringenslider-wrapper">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2><?php _e('Popular models'); ?></h2>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>  

    <ul class="ringenslider">

        <li class="product-slide">

            <div class="product-slide-wrap">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hyEkF58.png" alt="" />                
                </div>

                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Steinberg Ring 1</h3>
                    <div class="prijs">
                        €499
                    </div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
                    </p>

                    <div class="button-slider-wrap">
                        <a class="button-slider" href="#">
                            Nu bestellen
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </li>

        <li class="product-slide">

            <div class="product-slide-wrap">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hyEkF58.png" alt="" />

                </div>

                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Steinberg Ring 1</h3>
                    <div class="prijs">
                        €499
                    </div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
                    </p>

                    <div class="button-slider-wrap">
                        <a class="button-slider" href="#">
                            Nu bestellen
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="product-slide">

            <div class="product-slide-wrap">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hyEkF58.png" alt="" />

                </div>

                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Steinberg Ring 1</h3>
                    <div class="prijs">
                        €499
                    </div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
                    </p>

                    <div class="button-slider-wrap">
                        <a class="button-slider" href="#">
                            Nu bestellen
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="product-slide">

            <div class="product-slide-wrap">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hyEkF58.png" alt="" />

                </div>

                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Steinberg Ring 1</h3>
                    <div class="prijs">
                        €499
                    </div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
                    </p>

                    <div class="button-slider-wrap">
                        <a class="button-slider" href="#">
                            Nu bestellen
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="product-slide">

            <div class="product-slide-wrap">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hyEkF58.png" alt="" />

                </div>

                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Steinberg Ring 1</h3>
                    <div class="prijs">
                        €499
                    </div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
                    </p>

                    <div class="button-slider-wrap">
                        <a class="button-slider" href="#">
                            Nu bestellen
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="product-slide">

            <div class="product-slide-wrap">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hyEkF58.png" alt="" />

                </div>

                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Steinberg Ring 1</h3>
                    <div class="prijs">
                        €499
                    </div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
                    </p>

                    <div class="button-slider-wrap">
                        <a class="button-slider" href="#">
                            Nu bestellen
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="product-slide">

            <div class="product-slide-wrap">

                <div class="product-image">

                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hyEkF58.png" alt="" />

                </div>

                <div class="product-info">
                    <h3>Steinberg Ring 1</h3>
                    <div class="prijs">
                        €499
                    </div>
                    <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.
                    </p>

                    <div class="button-slider-wrap">
                        <a class="button-slider" href="#">
                            Nu bestellen
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </li>

    </ul>


</section>
```

JS:

```
(function ($) {

    "use strict";


    $(document).ready(function() {

  //Ringenslider
         $('.ringenslider').slick({
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            draggable: false,
            centerMode:false,
            swipe: false,
            dots:false,
            fade:false,
            speed:745,
            cssEase: 'ease',
            useTransform: true,
            nextArrow: '<a class="slide-next">Volgende <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
            prevArrow: '<a class="slide-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> Vorige</a>',
            variableWidth: true,
            responsive: [{
                        breakpoint: 1200
                        , settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3
                        }
                    }, {
                        breakpoint: 992
                        , settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2
                        }
                    }, {
                        breakpoint: 768
                        , settings: {
                            speed: 250
                            , arrows: !1
                            , swipe: !0
                            , centerMode: !0
                            , slidesToShow: 1
                        }
                    }]

        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

CSS:

```
    /* Ringenslider Wrapper */
.ringenslider-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0 0 80px 0;
}

.ringenslider-wrapper h2 {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:72px;
    line-height:72px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url('../images/ring-titel-bg.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;

}

.ringenslider-wrapper h2::before {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    content:'';
    width:300px;
    top:50%;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#cae1ef;
}
.ringenslider-wrapper h2::after {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    content:'';
    width:300px;
    top:50%;
    height:1px;
    background-color:#cae1ef;
}



@media(max-width:767px){
    .ringenslider-wrapper h2::after {
        display:none;
    }
    .ringenslider-wrapper h2::before {
        display:none;
    }
}

@media(min-width:768px){
    .ringenslider-wrapper h2::after {
        right:-120px;
    }
    .ringenslider-wrapper h2::before {
        left:-120px;
    }
}

@media(min-width:992px){
    .ringenslider-wrapper h2::after {
        right:-30px;
    }
    .ringenslider-wrapper h2::before {
        left:-30px;
    }   
}

@media(min-width:1200px){
    .ringenslider-wrapper h2::after {
        right:0px;
    }
    .ringenslider-wrapper h2::before {
        left:0px;
    }   
}




/* RINGENSLIDER */
.ringenslider {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.ringenslider .slick-slider {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
    touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.ringenslider .slick-track {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0 ;

}

.ringenslider li {
    min-height:1px;
    width: 318px;
    height: 279px !important;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition: all 750ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 750ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 750ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 750ms ease;
    transition: all 750ms ease;

    box-sizing: border-box; 

    outline:none;

    margin:20px 20px 20px 20px;

}

.product-slide-wrap {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}


.ringenslider li::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 279px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;

    background: rgb(248,248,248); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%, rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(248,248,248,1) 0%,rgba(234,234,234,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8f8f8', endColorstr='#eaeaea',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    box-shadow:         0px 0px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
}

.ringenslider li h3 {
    font-size:22px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin:0 0 0px 0;
    color:#5689a8;
}

.ringenslider li .prijs {
    font-size:22px;
    line-height:28px;
    margin:0;
    color:#454444;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
}


.ringenslider li .product-info {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 13px 0;
    max-width: 440px;
    -webkit-transition: all 750ms;
    -moz-transition: all 750ms;
    -ms-transition: all 750ms;
    -o-transition: all 750ms;
    transition: all 750ms;
}


.ringenslider li .product-image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.ringenslider li .product-image img {
    max-width: 138px;
    max-height: 212px;
    display: inline-block !important;
    transform: translate3d(160px, 60px, 0) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(160px, 60px, 0) scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 750ms;
    -moz-transition: all 750ms;
    -ms-transition: all 750ms;
    -o-transition: all 750ms;
    transition: all 750ms;
}

.ringenslider li p {
    color: #454444;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 750ms;
    -moz-transition: all 750ms;
    -ms-transition: all 750ms;
    -o-transition: all 750ms;
    transition: all 750ms;
}
.ringenslider li .button-slider-wrap {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 750ms;
    -moz-transition: all 750ms;
    -ms-transition: all 750ms;
    -o-transition: all 750ms;
    transition: all 750ms;
}

/* RINGENSLIDER BUTTON */

.button-slider {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    font-size:19px;
    line-height:19px;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:15px 30px;
    font-weight:500;
    outline:none;
}

.button-slider:link {
    color:#5689a8;
    border: 2px solid #5689a8;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}
.button-slider:visited {
    color:#5689a8;
    border: 2px solid #5689a8;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}
.button-slider:hover {
    color:#fff;
    border: 2px solid #5689a8;
    background:#5689a8;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}
.button-slider:active {
    color:#fff;
    border: 2px solid #5689a8;
    background:#5689a8;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
}




/* RINGENSLIDER ACTIVE */

.ringenslider li.slick-active .product-slide-wrap {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-70px, 0px);
    transform: translate(0px, 0px);
    width: calc(100% + 460px);
    max-width: initial;
} 

.ringenslider li.slick-active, .ringenslider li.slick-active  {
     width:778px;
}

.ringenslider li.slick-active img {  
    transform: translate3d(125px, 0px, 0) scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(125px, 0px, 0) scale(1.2);
}

.ringenslider li.slick-active .product-info {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(336px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(336px, 0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(336px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(336px, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms;
    -o-transition: all 500ms;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

.ringenslider li.slick-active h3 {
    font-size:26px;
    line-height:34px;
}

.ringenslider li.slick-active .prijs {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 34px;
}

.ringenslider li.slick-active p {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}

.ringenslider li.slick-active .button-slider-wrap {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 200ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 200ms;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
}

/* RINGSLIDER ARROWS */
.slick-disabled {
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}


.slide-next, .slide-prev {
    visibility:visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 180px;
    bottom: -30px;
    z-index: 100;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:17px;
    line-height:27px;
    font-weight:300;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms;
    -ms-transition: all 250ms;
    -o-transition: all 250ms;
    transition: all 250ms;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
}

.slide-next i {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    height:27px;
    width:27px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 10px;
    font-size:19px;
    line-height:25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
    border:1px solid #5689a8;

    -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms;
    -ms-transition: all 250ms;
    -o-transition: all 250ms;
    transition: all 250ms;
}

.slide-prev i {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    height:27px;
    width:27px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 8px;
    font-size:19px;
    line-height:25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
    border:1px solid #5689a8;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.slide-next {
    left: auto;
    right: 180px;
}
.slide-prev {

}
.slide-next:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.slide-prev:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.slide-next:hover i {
    background-color:#5689a8;
    color:#fff;
}
.slide-prev:hover i {
    background-color:#5689a8;
    color:#fff;
}
```

I've tried different ways trying to fix this but the animation keeps jumping.

Help would be really appreciated.

Best regards,
Dylan Smit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i experienced same issue with a web site i made for a client in the past. I tried also alot of different sliders to realise that the same problem appears on them too. The problem is, Javavascript and jquery (if you use it), don't support well slide changes. This is not specefic to one slider. That cause glitch, jumping and many other issues. The solution i found was [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/) with [fireslider](https://github.com/mmonkey/fireSlider). But, if you find another slider with velocity or you make your own, that will work too.

Velocity is a engine to fast motions and work with javascript and jquery(optional) as well. But if you take fireslider, you need jquery.

I Hope that will help you.

Comment: Transitions seem to go smooth yes. However FireSlider calculates a slidewidth in percentage and also it's transitions are based on percentages. Do you have any clue on how set the activeslide width + the other slides using velocity.js.

Comment: Ok, if i understand well, you want set the width of your slides in another unit like pixels, em, rem etc... The easiest way i see is by your css file. Create class for these images and set them in this class to the size you want and if you want different sizes for each, do it with the id. I think it's the best solution. Or if you feel easy, you can make changes in fireslider code, but that is the most complicate choice. I hope it will help you.